# css resizing input box

Tags: css

I'm trying to reduce the size of an input box on a mobile device and the css won't work.

I used google dev tools to get the name of the element (input#calc_shipping_postcode.input-text) but when I try and specify the width in CSS nothing happens.. the page is -https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/flower-delivery/

the CSS i'm trying to use is -

```
    input#calc_shipping_postcode.input-text {
    width: 270px;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: there is an inline width applied for the element. Remove it and then add your css. or try adding !important to the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your site is that width are set to `350px` by inline styling.

This is caused from some wordpress plugin (maybe this set from WPBakey).

One solution is to find out what is causing this styling in wordpress then edit it.

Other fast workaround solution is to override ths by adding `!important` to your css property like:

```
input#calc_shipping_postcode.input-text {
  width: 270px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instated of adding width in `px` use `%`. will work in all devices.

try this.

```
input#calc_shipping_postcode {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Nope,This won't change the width.

Comment: you can try this will work as fluid try doing that and then let me know.

Comment: I've just tried it, But maybe you've misunderstood the question. The question is about reducing the width. but with your code the width will remain `350px`, Maybe you mean `270px` not `350`

Comment: i did mention if you use px will solve the issue but leave the space in landscape but if it in % will look perfect as bootstrap will max -width 350.